# Simple Closed Contour Integral with a simple pole equalling 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Out of curiosity, can a function with simple poles have their contour integral equalling to 0?
I ask because, say for the function $\ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$, if we integrate it around the closed contour $|z| = 1$, it will be equal to 0 by the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, for $g(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ we cannot say the same because the antiderivative would not be holomorphic along the contour - it has a discontinuity along the negative real axis. Can this be generalised to all functions with simple poles within the contour?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb C$, r>0, $D=\{z \in \mathbb C: 0<|z-z_0|<r\}$ and suppose that $f:D \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and has a simple pole at $z_0$. Then , by Laurent, we have

$$f(z)= \frac{a}{z-z_0}+g(z)$$

with $a \ne 0$ and $g: \{z \in \mathbb C: |z-z_0|<r\} \to \mathbb C$ holomorphic.

Now let $0< \rho <r$. Then we have

$$ \int_{|z-z_0|= \rho} f(z) dz= a\int_{|z-z_0|= \rho} \frac{dz}{z-z_0}+\int_{|z-z_0|= \rho} g(z) dz.$$

Since $\int_{|z-z_0|= \rho} g(z) dz=0$ and $\int_{|z-z_0|= \rho}\frac{dz}{z-z_0}=2 \pi i$, we derive

$$ \int_{|z-z_0|= \rho} f(z) dz= a 2 \pi i \ne 0.$$

Comment: Interesting. Could this argument extend beyond just a single simple pole? For example two poles with residues equal and opposite (and hence cancel).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to look at this from the point of view of Cauchy's integral.

Cauchy's integral: Let $f$ be analytic around the origin, then
$$ f(v) = \oint\frac{f(z)}{z-v}dz $$
if everything is taken in the domain of analyticity and $v$ is enclosed by the contour of integration.
We can differentiate this relation and we get
$$ f^{(n)}(v) = \oint\frac{n!f(z)}{(z-v)^{n+1}}dz. $$
This implies that
$$ f^{(n)}(0) = \oint\frac{n!f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz $$
which can be rewritten as
$$ \oint\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} $$
Now let $f$ be constant, $f(v)=c$ then we have
$$ \oint\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz = \oint\frac{c}{z^{n+1}}dz = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}. $$
This means that unless $n=0$, the integral vanishes.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your very first question, sure. Take $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ $-$ it has a residue of $0$ at its pole.

Comment: @ Ninad: $ \frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $0$ and not a pole !

Comment: @Fred yes, that's a possibility for what a residue of $0$ could mean. A removable singularity is a pole of order $0$, after all.

Comment: The OP talks about simple (!) poles.

Comment: @Fred You should think about the defintion of a residue for a moment.  A pole is simply represented any function that can be written as $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ where $f$ must be analytic. Now, I don't know about you, but $\sin z$ looks analytic to me. To calculate a residue for a simple pole at $0$, you can take the limit $\lim_{z\to 0} z \frac{f(z)}{z} = f(0)$. Call it whatever you want, but by that defintion if the residue of what we treated as a simple pole is $0$, then it just means the singularity vanished. If you want to be rigid, then a residue $0$ means the $z^{-1}$ term isn't present.

Comment: @ Ninad: what you wrote is not true ! If $f$ has a simple pole at $0$ , then $\lim_{z\to 0} z \frac{f(z)}{z} = f(0)$ is false, since $f$ is not defined at $0$. Furthermore, the residue of $f$ at the simple pole $0$ is given by $\lim_{z\to 0} z f(z)$.

Comment: @Fred I'll speak more slowly: a function $g$ has a pole if it can be written as $\frac{f(z)}{z}$. If that pole happens to vanish, then that's okay then the "pole" never really existed.

Comment: very, very, very , very slowly: a pole of order $ \ge 1$ never "vanish", the pole exists ! A removably singularity is not a pole !

Comment: @Fred Objectively, semantically, you are wrong, [have a look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Other_kinds_of_singularities) at point 1. As a sidenote, you should be more respectful and less of an asshole to others. From the very first comment you came in guns blazing yelling, not to mention acting intentionally obtuse towards my explanations and unwilling to listen to reason. This not the way to behave, and you should be ashamed of yourself, as I am of myself for how I reacted.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting example, however I in particular meant in regards to non removable singularities because the residue of sin(z)/z is obviously zero.